# Как лучше всего рассчитывать прогресс выполнения и задавать его цену?

Tags: c#

Есть некая операция, которое состоит из последовательности действий.

```
void MyOperation
{
    Action1();
    Action2();
    Action3();
}
```

Потребовалось повесить на это просмотр текущего прогресса. Причем на случай изменения действий (добавления, удаления, изменения цены действия), управление прогрессом не должно быть сложным и требовать пересчеты на калькуляторе.

```
void MyOperation
{
    [CostAttribute(30)]
    Action1();
    [CostAttribute(40)]
    Action2();
    [CostAttribute(30)]
    Action3();
}
```

А в самих функциях должен посчитаться общий прогресс (30 + 40 + 30) и текущий для действия (общий/текущий).

То есть если программист добавляет новое действие (Action4), он примерно оценивает, сколько оно будет выполняться и выставляет свою цену, например 100, не меняя остальные цены и соотношения.

Как такое можно сделать?

**UPD:**

Сначала мне пришло в голову сделать так. Поставить атрибут с ценой над каждым определением действия. Но действие может иметь разную цену в зависимости от контекста. Например, действие копирует файлы. В этом случае оно может использоваться в операции несколько раз, и цена его будет разная. Программист примерно представляет, сколько файлов имеется для копирования, а потому в одном случае это действие будет стоить 10 (примерно 1000 файлов), а в другом - 20 (примерно 2000 файлов). Короче не знаю как это сделать красивее и удобнее в понимании и программировании.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант, можно обернуть MyOperation и Action в классы. В этом случае MyOperation хранит набор Action и выполняет их поочередно. После выполнения действия можно пересчитать прогресс выполнения, используя параметр action.Weight (он же цена).

```
public class MyOperation
{ 
   List<MyAction> actions=new List<MyAction>()

   public void Run()
   {
      foreach(var action in actions)
      {
          action.Execute();
          this.ResearchProgress(action.weight);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: То же самое пришло в голову.... ну, кроме деталей. Уже почти реализовал )

Comment: А теперь встал вопрос, как двигать прогресс и во время выполнения Action